# QML: Signal isn't being called in a unit test

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qqmlcomponent, qsignalspy

I'm writing a C++ class `ScriptProcess`, meant to be used in QML, that acts as an interface to a child process.  Said child process loads a script, then executes functions on demand.  When you call a function, the result (be it a value or an exception) is returned asynchronously through signals.

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtTest 1.0
import dungeon 1.0

TestCase {
    id: test
    name: "ScriptProcessTest"

    property ScriptProcess session: null

    signal exceptionWhenLoadingCode(string type, int line, string message)

    SignalSpy {
        id: exceptionSpy
        target: test
        signalName: "exceptionWhenLoadingCode"
    }

    Component {
        id: process

        ScriptProcess {
            id: script

            onExceptionWhenLoadingCode: test.exceptionWhenLoadingCode(type, line, message)
        }
    }

    function startScript(scriptUrl) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
        request.open("GET", "data/%1.js".arg(scriptUrl), false)
        request.send(null)

        return process.createObject(test, {code: request.responseText})
    }

    function cleanup() {
        if (session) {
          session.stop()
        }

        delete session
        session = null
    }

    function test_syntaxErrorInGlobalContextIsReported() {
        var count = exceptionSpy.count
        session = startScript("syntax-error-in-global-context")

        compare(exceptionSpy.count, count + 1)
    }

    function test_errorThrownInGlobalContextIsReported() {
        var count = exceptionSpy.count
        session = startScript("error-in-global-context")

        compare(exceptionSpy.count, count + 1)
    }
}
```

In a nutshell, I do the following:

1. For each test, open the auxillary process and load a script from a file.  This is done by instantiating a `Component`, with the script given via the `ScriptProcess.code` property.
2. Run the test.
3. When the test finishes, kill the process and delete the object that manages it.

My problem is that the `SignalSpy` called `exceptionSpy` is not being triggered; `exceptionSpy.count` is always zero, and I have no idea why.  **Why is this the case?  Am I misusing `SignalSpy` or `Component`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`XMLHttpRequest`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-qmlglobalobject.html#xmlhttprequest) is asynchronous, so you should probably change `startScript()` to something like:

```
function startScript(scriptUrl) {
    var object = process.createObject(test)

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE)
            object.code = request.responseText
    }
    request.open("GET", "data/%1.js".arg(scriptUrl), false)
    request.send(null)

    return object
}
```

And since the signal is not going to be emitted right away, you'll have to wait for it instead of comparing the count immediately after creating the object:

```
function test_foo() {
    var count = exceptionSpy.count
    session = startScript("...")

    tryCompare(exceptionSpy, "count", count + 1)
}
```